# What happens to globally allocated memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, global-variables, valgrind

I have a program like this:

```
int *number0 = new int;

int main()
{
    int *number1 = new int;
}
```

I thought, both memory allocations would introduce memory leaks, though valgrind only
complains about number1 inside the main function. Why is that?

Comment: It doesn't really matter since any memory will be freed on process termination. I'd guess that valgrind decides that memory which is pointed to by a global variable is not a memleak.

Comment: Before you conclude it's ok to do something like number0, though, remember that if were a class type instead of just an `int`, its destructor would not be called (maybe valgrind would complain in that case?)

Comment: @dlf: Exactly my problem: I thought, due to the absence of the valgrind warning, that the destructer of the object (represented by *number0) has been called somehow automatically, which of course is not the case, as I know now. I also don't think that it is ok to let process termination take care of manually allocated memory. I don't know why, but it sends chills down my spine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running this

```
int *x = new int;

int main()
{   
    return 0;
}
```

code (i.e **without** the leak in the main, compiled with g++ 4.8.1) using valgrind (3.8.1) with (`-v --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes`) I get:

```
==34301== 
==34301== HEAP SUMMARY:
==34301==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==34301==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==34301== 
==34301== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==34301== Checked 189,064 bytes
==34301== 
==34301== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==34301==    at 0x4C2A879: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==34301== 
==34301== LEAK SUMMARY:
==34301==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==34301==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==34301==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==34301==    still reachable: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==34301==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Which means that you should also pay attention to the `in use at exit` category.

It doesn't seem like valgrind missed it, just placed it in another category, possibly because they assume something as lost only when you cannot by any means track down that address and release it, but this variable is never *lost*.

This however :

```
int *x = new int;

int main()
{

    x = new int;    
    return 0;
}
```

Is detected as a leak as you really *lose track* of the memory you've allocated.

**EDIT:** As described in the Mem-check [manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html):

> "Still reachable". This covers cases 1 and 2 (for the BBB blocks)
>   above. A start-pointer or chain of start-pointers to the block is
>   found. Since the block is still pointed at, the programmer could, at
>   least in principle, have freed it before program exit. "Still
>   reachable" blocks are very common and arguably not a problem. So, by
>   default, Memcheck won't report such blocks individually.

So as noted before they do detect it, they just think it's less exciting

Answer (score 4):

Valgrind is not a perfect tool for detecting the presence or absence of all possible memory leaks, but rather a helpful tool that can detect some memory leaks. This means that valgrind output cannot be used to determine whether a particular piece of code contains or does not contain any leaks.

Neither of your `new`s have corresponding `delete`s, and in that sense, they are both leaked.

It is likely that valgrind considers the `number0` memory to not be leaked because the memory it points to is reachable at the end of the program execution. In contrast to this, `number1` goes out of scope, and so the memory it points to is not reachable at the end of the execution of your program, and so valgrind considers it to be leaked.

Answer (score 0):

I see two leaks using valgrind 3.8.1 / g++ 4.8.1:

```
$ g++ -o foo -g foo.cc
$ valgrind ./foo
...
==7789== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7789==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 2 blocks
==7789==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==7789== 
==7789== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7789==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==7789==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7789==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7789==    still reachable: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==7789==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The "definitely lost" bytes are in `main` in my test.

Comment: You don't have *ones* I'm afraid but only **one** in each category (one `int` (4 bytes) in the definitely lost category and one in the still reachable category) and I think that this is exactly what the OP was asking about, i.e why does valgrind put those seemingly identical leaks in different categories.

Comment: oh, now I see why the plural made sense :)

Answer (score -1):

This

```
  int *number0 = new int;
```

is not a memory leak because it gets reclaimed at the end of execution.

This configuration is a [potential] memory leak because

```
int main()
{
     int *number1 = new int;
}
```

some other part of the code could call

```
    main () ;
```

and it could be called repeatedly.

Comment: It isn't legal to call `main()` from within a `C++` program. (see `[basic.start.main]/3`: "The function main shall not be used within a program.")

Comment: It doesn't have to be a C++ program calling a C++ routine.